# Error in hibernate one to one mapping object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have two classes called `Instructor` and `InstructorDetails` which have a one-to-one relationship (bi directional) in hibernate.

When I save the object in to the database, I am getting an error of:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

I already referred to the previous answers in the Stackoverflow which tells to change the `CascadeType` to `ALL` and I already solved this issue by doing so, but I need to know what's really happening here?

For example, if in a case where you don't want the cascade delete like I did in my code, how can we achieve that? It seems that in every answer they tell to change cascade type to all, so how can we achieve that?

**Instructor class**

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Instructor")

public class Instructor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firtName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_detail_id")
    private InstructorDetails instructorDetail;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getFirtName() {
        return firtName;
    }


    public void setFirtName(String firtName) {
        this.firtName = firtName;
    }


    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }


    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public InstructorDetails getInstructorDetailId() {
        return instructorDetail;
    }


    public void setInstructorDetailId(InstructorDetails instructorDetail) {
        this.instructorDetail = instructorDetail;
    }


    public Instructor(String firtName, String lastName, String email) {
        super();
        this.firtName = firtName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Instructor() {

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Instructor [id=" + id + ", firtName=" + firtName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email
                + ", instructorDetail=" + instructorDetail + "]";
    }

}
```

**InstructorDetails Class**

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="instructor_detail")
public class InstructorDetails {
    //annotate the class as an entitty and map to db table


    //define the fields


    //annotate the fields with db column names


    //create constructors


    //generate getters and setters


    //generate toString() method
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy ="instructorDetail",cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH} )

    private Instructor instructor;


    public Instructor getInstructor() {
        return instructor;
    }


    public void setInstructor(Instructor instructor) {
        this.instructor = instructor;
    }


    @Column(name="youtube_channel")
    private String youTubeChannel;

    @Column(name="hobby")
    private String hobby;


    public InstructorDetails() {

    }


    public InstructorDetails(String youTubeChannel, String hobby) {
        super();
        this.youTubeChannel = youTubeChannel;
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getYouTubeChannel() {
        return youTubeChannel;
    }


    public void setYouTubeChannel(String youTubeChannel) {
        this.youTubeChannel = youTubeChannel;
    }


    public String getHobby() {
        return hobby;
    }


    public void setHobby(String hobby) {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InstructorDetails [id=" + id + ", youTubeChannel=" + youTubeChannel + ", hobby=" + hobby + "]";
    }

}
```

**Main class**

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Instructor;
import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.InstructorDetails;
import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class CreateDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //create session factory
        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class)
                            .addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetails.class);

        SessionFactory factory = con.buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {

            //create the objects
            InstructorDetails tempInstructorDetail = new InstructorDetails("http://luv2code.com/youtube","Luv 2 code");

            Instructor tempInstructor = new Instructor("Chad","lay","hasiay@.com");
            tempInstructorDetail.setInstructor(tempInstructor);
            tempInstructor.setInstructorDetailId(tempInstructorDetail);

            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(tempInstructor);

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("done!");

        }finally {
            factory.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have a question, why do you need bidirectional relationship in Instructor and InstructorDetail? It can be very well unidirectional, and other table will refer it by foreign key.. isnt it? bidirectional dependencies can also be called as cyclic, whcih is a bad design choice.

Comment: @AnandVaidya I am doing this project for my educational purposes so I need to know in a case like this how to do it?

Comment: Ok.. give me some time.

Comment: @AnandVaidya sure!, thank you